# Finding Inputs without labels

Tags: javascript, react-testing-library

how can I find an input without labels?

```
--------------------------------------------------
  radio:

  Name "":
  <input
    class="M8E MIw e43 xpn ac9 BG7"
    id="not-blocked"
    name="not-blocked"
    type="radio"
    value="not-blocked"
  />

  Name "":
  <input
    class="M8E MIw e43 xpn ac9 BG7"
    id="blocked"
    name="blocked"
    type="radio"
    value="blocked"
  />
```

I tried `container.querySelector('input')[0]` but that fails. I can't add labels directly to the radiobutton because of styling reasons

Comment: If you want to use subscripts/square brackets and pick from an array of inputs inside `container`, try `container.querySelectorAll('input')[0]`. querySelectorAll() returns an array.

Comment: Ah tried but returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

querySelector is used for CSS tags.

Use getElementsByTagName instead.

Comment: Oh I was able to find the element using `screen.getByDisplayValue('not-blocked');`